DigitalOcean fails to start next app after successful build
I am trying to deploy a simple NEXT app on DigitalOcean. Local build and start works perfectly fine and by all means it should work on DigitalOcean. However after a successful build I get the following error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/.next/BUILD_ID'
I've looked inside the files and I have managed to find the BUILD_ID inside .next/ folder.
The only thing I can think of is that for some reason it tries to access the /workspace directory inside the project.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
